# IntelliJ Idea not resolving Mockito and JUnit dependencies with Maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit, mockito

I am using `IntelliJ idea` for writing simple unit test cases using `JUnit` and `Mockito`. I am using Maven for dependency management.

`IntelliJ idea` keeps complaining that following imports cannot be resolved:

```
import org.junit.Test; //Cannot resolve symbol 'Test'

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*; //Cannot resolve symbol 'mockito'
```

Following is the `dependencies` section of my project:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Dependency for JUnit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
    </dependency>
    <!-- Dependency for Mockito -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Following is my project structure:

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: Try to right click on you project, then in the menu -> maven -> Download Sources (or Reimport)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `View` -> `Tool Windows` -> `Maven projects`, then click the blue icon in the top left of the tool window (`Reimport all Maven projects`). You should be able to find the dependencies in the project view, under external libraries.

If this does not work, there is probably something wrong with your maven config (pom.xml). Try `mvn clean install` from the command line see if it gives any errors.

Comment: Because sometimes Idea has hick-ups :)

Comment: Some hiccup @Matt!

Comment: Usually when you change a pom-file tracked by IDEA, you get a small popup in your lower right corner asking you if you want to reimport the project (or enable autoimport). Changes done to the pom file has no effect until a reimport is completed.

Comment: @Tobb Yeah! That's the usual case, but I was not getting that pop-up in this case. However, the `Reimport` worked for me. Thanks again :)

Comment: And for Scala / sbt projects: Try `View` -> `Tool Windows` -> `Sbt projects`, then right click on the project and (`Reimport sbt project`).

If this does not work, in the sbt console do manual `clean` then `update` and then `compile`.

Answer (score 2):

My IDE was not resolving JUnit & Mockito dependencies. Tried reimport in IntelliJ and mvn clean install multiple times which didn't help. Reimport worked for me, but with the following steps.

**Please be aware that you will lose any run configurations that you have created.**

1. Close IntelliJ
2. Go to Project Folder and remove .idea folder (rm -rf ./idea)
3. Import Maven project again (You will need to add back any run configurations that were deleted)

Answer (score 2):

Restartig intellIJ fixed that for me

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding mockito to module I used. Just go to `File` -> `Project structure` and in `Modules` add mockito to your selected module - the one in which you use mockito (usually `Test`).

Answer (score 1):

Try using lower versions of junit and mockito.

The latest versions weren't working in my project but it worked once I used lower versions.

Few other things you can do:

- After adding the dependency just make sure to update the maven
  project. (right-click on project folder -> Maven -> Reload project)
- You can also try clicking on the tiny m symbol on the top right to
  load maven changes or select maven button to get clean+install
  options and click play button.

[image: Maven Reload project]

[image: Maven Load and Clean Install options]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use command

> mvn -U idea:idea

This command forces a check for missing dependencies and helps in resolving them.

Comment: The maven idea plugin is retired, and not really useful. Better to let IDEA generate the idea files based on the pom.xml. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-idea-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

For me, I deleted org.mockito package from m2 repository and then did mvn clean install.
this reimport the package.

Answer (score 0):

File -> Invalid Caches does the trick for me.